# Get highest score in this game: choosing and removing elements in an array

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

**Given an array `arr` of `n` integers, what is the highest score that a player can reach, playing the following game?**

1. Choose an index 0 < `i` < n-1 in the array
2. Add `arr[i-1] * arr[i+1]` points to the score (initially the score is 0)
3. Shrink the array by removing element `i` (`forall j >= i: arr[j] = arr[j+1]; then n = n - 1`
4. Repeat steps 1-3 until `n == 2`.

Do the above until there are only 2 elements (which are the first and the last element because you can't remove them).

What is the highest score you can get ?

**Example**

```
arr = [1 2 3 4]
```

- Choose `i=2`, get: 2*4  = 8 points, remove 3

Remaining: `arr = [1 2 4]`

- Choose `i=1`,  get 1*4 = 4 points, remove 2

Remaining: `arr = [1 4]`.

The sum of points is 8 + 4 = 12, which is the highest possible score on this example.

I think it is related to Dynamic programming but I'm not sure how to solve it.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you please rephrase the question? If you can't rephrase the question, can you please give an example with a small array and an example of execution of this `choose an element / get points` procedure? What does "you'll get c[i-1]*c[i+1] points" mean??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem has a dynamic programming approach similar to [Matrix-chain multiplication problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_chain_multiplication). You can find further explanation in the book "Introduction to Algorithms", 3rd Edition (Cormen, page 370).

Let's find the optimal substructure property and then use it to construct an optimal solution to the problem from optimal solutions to subproblems.
Notation: C<sub>i..j</sub>, where i ≤ j, stands for elements C<sub>i</sub>,C<sub>i+1</sub>,...,C<sub>j</sub>.
Definition: A removal sequence for C<sub>i..j</sub> is a permutation of i+1,i+2,...,j-1.
A removal sequence for C<sub>i..j</sub> is optimal if the score achieved by removing the elements of C<sub>i..j</sub> in that order is maximum among all possible removal sequences for C<sub>i..j</sub>.

**1. Characterize the structure of an optimal solution** 
If the problem is nontrivial, i.e. i + 1 < j, then any solution has a last removed element which corresponding index is k in the range
i < k < j. Such k split the problem into C<sub>i..k</sub> and C<sub>k..j</sub>. That is, for some value k, we first remove non extremal elements of C<sub>i..k</sub> and C<sub>k..j</sub> and then we remove element k. As removing non extremal elements of C<sub>i..k</sub> doesn't affect score obtained by removing non extremal elements of C<sub>k..j</sub> and an analogous reasoning for removing non extremal elements of C<sub>k..j</sub> is also true we state that both subproblems are independent. Then, for a given removal sequence where kth-element is last, the score of C<sub>i..j</sub> is equal to the sum of scores of C<sub>i..k</sub> and C<sub>k..j</sub>, plus the score of removing kth-element (C[i] * C[j]).

The optimal substructure of this problem is as follows. Suppose there is an optimal removal sequence O for C<sub>i..j</sub> that ends at kth-element, then the ordering of removed elements from C<sub>i..k</sub> must be optimal too. We can prove it by contradiction: If there was a removal sequence for C<sub>i..k</sub> that scored higher than removal subsequence extracted from O for C<sub>i..k</sub> then we can produce another removal sequence for C<sub>i..j</sub> with higher score than optimal removal sequence (**contradiction**). A similar observation holds for the ordering of removed elements from C<sub>k..j</sub> in the optimal removal sequence for C<sub>i..j</sub>: it must be optimal too.

We can build an optimal solution for nontrivial instances of the problem by splitting the problem into two subproblems, finding optimal solutions to subproblem instances, and them combining these optimal subproblem solutions.

**2. Recursively define the value of an optimal solution**.

For this problem our subproblems are the maximum score obtained in C<sub>i..j</sub> for 1 ≤ i ≤ j ≤ N. Let S[i, j] be the maximum score obtained in C<sub>i..j</sub>; for the full problem, the highest score when evaluating the given rules is S[1, N].

We can define S[i, j] recursively as follows:
If j ≤ i + 1 then S[i, j] = 0
If i + 1 < j then S[i, j] = max<sub>i < k < j</sub>{S[i, k] + S[k, j] + C[i] * C[j]}

We ensure that we search for the correct place to split because we consider all possible places, so that we are sure of having examined the optimal one.

**3. Compute the value of an optimal solution**

You can use your favorite method to compute S:
top-down approach (recursive)
bottom-up approach (iterative)\

I would use bottom-up for computing the solution since it would be < 5 lines long in almost any programming language.

Example in C++11:

```
for(int l = 2; l <= N; ++l) \\ increasing length intervals
    for(int i = 1, j = i + l; j <= N; ++i, ++j)
        for(int k = i + 1; k < j; ++k)
            S[i, j] = max(S[i, j], S[i, k] + S[k, j] + C[i] * C[j])
```

**4. Time Complexity and Space Complexity**

There are nC2 + n = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) subproblems and every subproblem do an operation which running time is Θ(l) where l is length of the subproblem so the math yield a running time of Θ(n<sup>3</sup>) for the algorithm (it's easy to spot the O(n<sup>3</sup>) part :-)). Also, the algorithm requires Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) space to store the S table.